# Why is an entity index displayed as id and not index

Tags: featuretools

The following defines an EntitySet. I've declared `did` as `Index` on the transaction table `tx` but it registers as `Id`, not `Index`. Why is that?

The objective is to remove the warning below.

Under what circumstances would an `Index` assignment be overridden as `Id` (primary vs. external key?), and is the fact that `did` registers as `Id` related to the warning?

One `uid` can have several `did`s in the `tx` table.

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id="the_entity_set")

# hse
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="hse",
                              dataframe=hse,
                              index="uid",
                              variable_types={"Gender": ft.variable_types.Categorical,
                                              "Income": ft.variable_types.Numeric,
                                              "dob"   : ft.variable_types.Datetime})

# types
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="types",
                              dataframe=types,
                              index="type_id",
                              variable_types={"type": ft.variable_types.Categorical})

# files
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="files",
                              dataframe=files,
                              index="file_id",
                              variable_types={"file": ft.variable_types.Categorical})

# uid_donations
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="uid_txlup",
                              dataframe=uid_txlup,
                              index="did",
                              variable_types={"uid": ft.variable_types.Categorical})

# transactions
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="tx",
                              dataframe=tx,
                              index="did",
                              time_index="dt",
                              variable_types={"file_id": ft.variable_types.Categorical,
                                              "type_id": ft.variable_types.Categorical,
                                              "amt":     ft.variable_types.Numeric})

rels = [
    ft.Relationship(es["files"]["file_id"],es["tx"]["file_id"]),
    ft.Relationship(es["types"]["type_id"],es["tx"]["type_id"]),
    ft.Relationship(es["hse"]["uid"],      es["uid_txlup"]["uid"]),
    ft.Relationship(es["uid_txlup"]["did"],es["tx"]["did"])
]

es.add_relationships( rels )
```

This is what the EntitySet looks like

```
Entityset: the_entity_set
  Entities:
    hse [Rows: 100, Columns: 4]
    types [Rows: 8, Columns: 2]
    files [Rows: 2, Columns: 2]
    uid_txlup [Rows: 336, Columns: 2]
    tx [Rows: 336, Columns: 5]
  Relationships:
    tx.file_id -> files.file_id
    tx.type_id -> types.type_id
    uid_txlup.uid -> hse.uid
    tx.did -> uid_txlup.did


es.entities

[Entity: hse
   Variables:
     uid (dtype: index)
     Gender (dtype: categorical)
     Income (dtype: numeric)
     dob (dtype: datetime)
   Shape:
     (Rows: 100, Columns: 4), Entity: types
   Variables:
     type_id (dtype: index)
     type (dtype: categorical)
   Shape:
     (Rows: 8, Columns: 2), Entity: files
   Variables:
     file_id (dtype: index)
     file (dtype: categorical)
   Shape:
     (Rows: 2, Columns: 2), Entity: uid_txlup
   Variables:
     did (dtype: index)
     uid (dtype: categorical)
   Shape:
     (Rows: 336, Columns: 2), Entity: tx
   Variables:
     did (dtype: id)            ### <<< external key ???
     dt (dtype: datetime)
     file_id (dtype: categorical)
     type_id (dtype: categorical)
     amt (dtype: numeric)
   Shape:
     (Rows: 336, Columns: 5)]
```

Why does `did` show up as `Id` and not `Index` when I call `fts`?

Here is the warning:

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                      target_entity="hse",
                                      agg_primitives=["sum","mode","percent_true"],
                                      where_primitives=["count", "avg_time_between"],
                                      max_depth=2)

feature_defs


.../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools-0.2.1-py3.6.egg/featuretools/entityset/entityset.py:432: FutureWarning: 'did' is both an index level and a column label.
Defaulting to column, but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version
  end_entity_id=child_eid)
```

Comment: The warning you are seeing is unrelated to the featuretools variable types. It comes from an upcoming API change in Pandas. This warning will go away in the next release of Featuretools and doesn't affect functionality in anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relationship in your entity set will always between an `Id` variable in the parent entity and an `Index` variable in the child entity. Therefore, featuretools will automatically convert the variable from the child entity to an `Index` type when you add the relationship regardless of what you specify.

There is the possibility that a variable is both an `Index` and an `Id` if there is a one-to-one relationship between entities. In this case, you should join the to two entities into one.